# after inserting java classes into packages and cucumber features into subdirectories: maven-cucumber-reporting does not generate report

Tags: selenium-webdriver, junit, maven-3, cucumber-java

I have common error on cucumber testexecution and reporting, but precondition of mine was not mentioned before: I structured my cucumber tests in subdirectories and packages - now the JUnit Runner works only in IDE not in maven build and no cucmber report is written. Error message is as such:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.masterthought:maven-cucumber-reporting:5.7.0:generate (execution) on project aec-s1-desktop-ui-testing: Execution execution of goal net.masterthought:maven-cucumber-reporting:5.7.0:generate failed: basedir /data/disk1/workspace/aec-s1-desktop-ui-testing/target/json-reports does not exist -> [Help 1]
```

pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                <version>5.7.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execution</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectName>cucumber-jvm-example</projectName>
                            <!-- optional, per documentation set this to "true" to bypass generation
                            of Cucumber Reports entirely, defaults to false if not specified -->
                            <skip>false</skip>
                            <!-- output directory for the generated report -->
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                            <!-- optional, defaults to outputDirectory if not specified -->
                            <inputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/json-reports</inputDirectory>
                            <jsonFiles>
                                <!-- supports wildcard or name pattern -->
                                <param>**/*.json</param>
                            </jsonFiles>
                            <!-- optional, defaults to outputDirectory if not specified -->
                            <classificationFiles>
                                <!-- supports wildcard or name pattern -->
                                <param>sample.properties</param>
                                <param>other.properties</param>
                            </classificationFiles>
                            <!--parallelTesting>false</parallelTesting-->
                            <!-- optional, set true to group features by its Ids -->
                            <mergeFeaturesById>false</mergeFeaturesById>
                            <!-- optional, set true to get a final report with latest results of the
                            same test from different test runs -->
                            <mergeFeaturesWithRetest>false</mergeFeaturesWithRetest>
                            <!-- optional, set true to fail build on test failures -->
                            <checkBuildResult>true</checkBuildResult>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Smoke1TestRunner.java:

```
package runners.smoketests;


import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"pretty",
                "html:target/default-cucumber-reports.html",
                "json:target/json-reports/cucumber2.json",
                "junit:target/xml-report/cucumber2.xml"},
        features = "src/test/resources/features",
        glue = "stepdefinitions",
        tags = "@smoketest1",
        dryRun = false

)

public class Smoke1TestRunner {
}
```

Comment: You're asking a question that suggests your tests don't run. However you provide information about the report plugin. Perhaps you can start with making sure your tests run and if they don't, write a question about that.

Comment: It's complicated:
- in IDE I can directly start the testrunner,s. above
- `mvn clean verify` executes the tests, too
- reports are never generated, last change was the packaging/subdirectories

Comment: Impossible to say then. You'll have to do the work to isolate the problem and explain it in such a way that others can reproduce it. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

runners.smoketests.Smoke1TestRunner.java now looks like this:

```
package runners.smoketests;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"pretty",
                "html:target/default-cucumber-reports2.html",
                "json:target/json-reports/cucumber2.json",
                "junit:target/xml-report/cucumber2.xml"},
        features = "src/test/resources/features/smoketests",
        glue = "stepdefinitions/smoketests",
        tags = "@smoketest1",
        dryRun = false

)

public class Smoke1TestRunner {
}
```